# Linux kernel - tracefs vs debugvs

Tags: debugging, linux-kernel, trace

How do `tracefs` and `debugfs` differ? It looks like both can trace functions, system calls, etc. When to go for `debugfs` and when should we should use `tracefs`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**You should use `/sys/kernel/tracing`.** Both `/sys/kernel/tracing` and `/sys/kernel/debug/tracing` are `tracefs` mounts, so in theory they are equivalent. However, the second one depends on `debugfs` being available (since it is created inside the `debugfs` mount).

Before `tracefs` was introduced, tracing was only available through `debugfs`, so the entry in `debugfs` (`/sys/kernel/debug/tracing`) was kept for backward compatibility with old applications. Now tracing does not depend on `debugfs` anymore and `tracefs` has its own separate mount point (`/sys/kernel/tracing`).

See [the relevant patch](https://lkml.org/lkml/2015/1/26/454):

> There has been complaints that tracing is tied too much to `debugfs`,
> as there are systems that would like to perform tracing, but do
> not mount `debugfs` for security reasons. That is because any subsystem
> may use `debugfs` for debugging, and these interfaces are not always
> tested for security.
>
> [...]
>
> To maintain backward compatibility with older tools that expect that the `tracing` directory is mounted with `debugfs`, the `tracing` directory
> is still created under `debugfs` and `tracefs` is automatically mounted there.

And indeed:

```
$ mount -t tracefs
tracefs on /sys/kernel/tracing type tracefs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
tracefs on /sys/kernel/debug/tracing type tracefs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
```

Comment: Note that the mounting of /sys/kernel/debug/tracing can be disabled by "CONFIG_TRACEFS_DISABLE_AUTOMOUNT=y".